# Spark structured streaming with python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to Spark structured streaming with Kafka and Python. 
Requirement: I need to process streaming data from Kafka (in JSON format) in Spark (perform transformations) and then store it in a database.

I have data in JSON format like, 
`{"a": 120.56, "b": 143.6865998138807, "name": "niks", "time": "2012-12-01 00:00:09"}`

I am planning to use `spark.readStream` for reading from Kafka like,

```
data = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe","test").load()
```

I referred [this link](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-python.html#) for reference but didn't get how to parse JSON data. I tried this,

```
data = data.selectExpr("CAST(a AS FLOAT)","CAST(b as FLOAT)", "CAST(name as STRING)", "CAST(time as STRING)").as[(Float, Float, String, String)]
```

but looks like it doesn't work.

Can anyone who has worked on Spark structured streaming with Python guide me to proceed with sample examples or links?

Using,

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("a", DoubleType()),
    StructField("b", DoubleType()),
    StructField("name", StringType()),
    StructField("time", TimestampType())])

inData = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe","test").load()
data = inData.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema))
query = data.writeStream.outputMode("Append").format("console").start()
```

Program runs but I am getting values on console as,

```
+-----------------------------------+
|jsontostruct(CAST(value AS STRING))|
+-----------------------------------+
|               [null,null,null,2...|
|               [null,null,null,2...|
+-----------------------------------+

17/04/07 19:23:15 INFO StreamExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "8e2355cb-0fd3-4233-89d8-34a855256b1e",
  "runId" : "9fc462e0-385a-4b05-97ed-8093dc6ef37b",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2017-04-07T19:23:15.013Z",
  "numInputRows" : 2,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 125.0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 12.269938650306749,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 112,
    "getBatch" : 8,
    "getOffset" : 2,
    "queryPlanning" : 4,
    "triggerExecution" : 163,
    "walCommit" : 26
  },
  "eventTime" : {
    "watermark" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaSource[Subscribe[test]]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "test" : {
        "0" : 366
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "test" : {
        "0" : 368
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 2,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 125.0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 12.269938650306749
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSink@6aa91aa2"
  }
}
```

Did I miss something here.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `from_json` with schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("a", DoubleType()),
    StructField("b", DoubleType()), 
    StructField("name", StringType()), 
    StructField("time", TimestampType())])

data.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema))
```

or get individual fields as strings with `get_json_object`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object

data.select([
    get_json_object(col("value").cast("string"), "$.{}".format(c)).alias(c)
    for c in ["a", "b", "name", "time"]])
```

and `cast` them later according to your needs.