# Unresolved reference while trying to import col from pyspark.sql.functions in python 3.5

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Refer to the post here:
[Spark structured streaming with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284380/spark-structured-streaming-with-python)
I would like to import 'col' in python 3.5

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

However I got an error saying unresolved reference to col. I've installed pyspark library, so just wondering has the 'col' been removed from pyspark library? And how can I import the 'col' then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find col function in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163106/cannot-find-col-function-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out to be IntelliJ IDEA's problem. Even though it shows unresolved reference, my program still runs without any problem in the command line.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40163314/1226722) explains this behaviour very well.

Comment: The reason is correct, but it doesn't provide the actual solution

Answer (score 14):

Try installing ['pyspark-stubs'](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-stubs), I had the same problem in PyCharm and by doing it I resolved it.

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge pyspark-stubs` worked for me

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to get rid of this annoying issue.

Answer (score 2):

The function like `col` is not an explicit function defined in python code, but rather dynamically generated.

It will also report an error by static analysis tool like `pylint`

So the easiest way to use it shall be something like this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

F.col("colname")
```

The following code in `python/pyspark/sql/functions.py`

```
_functions = {
    'lit': _lit_doc,
    'col': 'Returns a :class:`Column` based on the given column name.',
    'column': 'Returns a :class:`Column` based on the given column name.',
    'asc': 'Returns a sort expression based on the ascending order of the given column name.',
    'desc': 'Returns a sort expression based on the descending order of the given column name.',

    'upper': 'Converts a string expression to upper case.',
    'lower': 'Converts a string expression to upper case.',
    'sqrt': 'Computes the square root of the specified float value.',
    'abs': 'Computes the absolute value.',

    'max': 'Aggregate function: returns the maximum value of the expression in a group.',
    'min': 'Aggregate function: returns the minimum value of the expression in a group.',
    'count': 'Aggregate function: returns the number of items in a group.',
    'sum': 'Aggregate function: returns the sum of all values in the expression.',
    'avg': 'Aggregate function: returns the average of the values in a group.',
    'mean': 'Aggregate function: returns the average of the values in a group.',
    'sumDistinct': 'Aggregate function: returns the sum of distinct values in the expression.',
}

def _create_function(name, doc=""):
    """ Create a function for aggregator by name"""
    def _(col):
        sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
        jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
        return Column(jc)
    _.__name__ = name
    _.__doc__ = doc
    return _

for _name, _doc in _functions.items():
    globals()[_name] = since(1.3)(_create_function(_name, _doc))
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be issue with PyCharm editor, me too able to run program with trim() through Python console.